# Android. Не спрашивать чем читать NFC метку, если программа уже запущена

Tags: java, android, nfc

Доброго времени суток.
Пишу программу для чтения и записи данных через NFC.
С работой самой программы проблем нет, но есть проблема с запуском.
Если установлено несколько программ - при контакте с NFC устройством ОС предлагает выбрать какую запустить, даже если моя запущена. Если выбрать мою корректно отрабатывает запущенный код. Если запущена сторонняя программа - повторный запрос не предлагается.
Вопрос в том - как "сказать" андройду, что не надо спрашивать чем читать метку, если программа уже запущена.
Манифест:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="aaa.nfctest">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="standard">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".nfc" android:launchMode="singleTask">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
            android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter"/>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

В программе (пока ещё прототипе) чтение метки осуществляется при запуске в onCreate, если программа запущена - в onNewIntent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте [Foreground Dispatch System](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch).

Другая идея. Если метки ваши, то можно добавить [AAR](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar) в метки, тогда будет вызываться только ваше приложение.

Comment: Foreground Dispatch System помог. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваша программа общего назначения, то никак. У пользователя может быть много похожих приложений и только он может решать какое хочет запустить.

Comment: Если ни одно не запущено - согласен, но если уже запущено приложение - зачем спрашивать заново? Тем-более, что при запущенной сторонней программе запрос чем открыть не происходит - метка читается в активном приложении.